# combine rows of table into one row in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have table like below

```
City       Area   Fruit     Price    As On  
XXX        111X   A         10       01-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   A         15       02-Oct-14   
XXX        111X   B         10       01-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   B         20       02-Oct-14  
.....
```

This data i need in Crystal reports in below format

```
XXX  
A  
City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   A        10           15

B
City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   B        10           20
```

I tried in many ways to group the data but not getting desired result
i dont want to use the cross tab
Please help me out on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of requirement:

1. Group by `Fruit` first.

Then place the `City`, `Area` and `Fruit` in detail section

2. For dates use `Crosstab` take the cross tab exactly after `Area` and take date in the crosstab.

Edit...................................................

if crosstab shouldn't be used then write below

create 2 formulas:

1. `@Firstdate'

   ```
   if As On='01-Oct-14'
   then price
   ```
2. `@seconddate'

   ```
   if As On='02-Oct-14'
   then price
   ```

place both formulas after `Fruit` in detail section

Hi Siva it is displaying i tried with above formula bu i got below

```
XXX

A

City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14

XXX        111X   A        10           0
XXX        111X   A        0           15
B
City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14

XXX        111X   B        10           0
XXX        111X   B        0           20
```

Comment: Hi Siva it is displaying i tried with above formula bu i got below<br><pre><br>                                                   XXX  
A  
City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   A        10           0
XXX        111X   A        0           15
B
City       Area   Fruit    01-Oct-14    02-Oct-14  
XXX        111X   B        10           0
XXX        111X   B        0           20
</pre>

Comment: ok in this case place `City`, `Area` and `Fruit` in group footer and formulas in details and take summary in group footer and supress details.. this will work